# flask request.args.getlist returns empty list

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I am new to web development and trying to solve the following problem. My app has several checkboxes and I need to get values of checked checkboxes. Later, I use those values in further data manipulations and pass the final result using ajax. When I try:

```
values = request.args.getlist('check')
print values
```

the list is empty.

```
values = request.values.getlist('check')
```

doesn't work ether.

Flask portion:

```
@app.route('/smiles_to_chemfig')
def smiles_to_chemfig():
    smiles_mol = request.args.get("smiles_mol")
    values = request.args.getlist('check')
    print values
    lst = ' '.join(values)
    chemfig, pdflink = smiles_mol_to_chemfig(lst,'-i direct', smiles_mol)       
    return jsonify(outcome = chemfig, pdf_link = pdflink)
```

ajax:

```
$(function(){
    $("button#smiles").on('click', function(){

    if ($('textarea[name=smiles_mol]').val()=="") {
            //$("#txt_area").html("PLEASE FILL OUT THIS FIELD !")
            alert("PLEASE FILL OUT THIS FIELD !");
        }
     else {
        $.getJSON('/smiles_to_chemfig', {
            smiles_mol: $('textarea[name=smiles_mol]').val()
        }, function(data) {
            $("#txt_area").text(data.outcome);
            console.log(data.outcome);
            $("#pdf").attr('src', data.pdf_link);
        });
        }
    return false;
    });    
});
```

I suspect, that it has something to do with ajax because if I do not implement ajax everything woks good but I need to use ajax. Any suggestions and comments are highly appreciated!

Comment: Post the ajax code too

Comment: It doesn't look like you're sending the checkbox form information anywhere, you're only sending the textarea info.

Comment: @Doobeh Thanks for pointing that out. I modified the code. My original code contains lst, I just missed that part while typing.